# Sorting a bound ASP.NET GridView on the Count of items in an Entity Framework navigation property

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, data-binding, gridview, entitydatasource

I have an ASP.NET page with a GridView control bound to an EntityDataSource (see simplified code below).  The grid is showing a list of `Parent` items and includes a column to show the .Count of `Children` for this parent.  I can get the grid to show the count properly, but I can't figure out what to use for the asp:TemplateField SortExpression value to be able to set the sort to the count of children.

Here is what my code looks like (simplified for clarity)...

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="edsParentList" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="name=FooEntities" 
     DefaultContainerName="FooEntities" 
     EnableFlattening="False" 
     EntitySetName="Parents" 
     EntityTypeFilter="Parent"
     Include="Children"
     OrderBy="it.Name"
     Where="(it.Name LIKE '%' + @ParentNameLike + '%')
     >
     <WhereParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="ParentNameLike" Type="String" DefaultValue="_" />
     </WhereParameters>
 </asp:EntityDataSource>
 <asp:GridView ID="grdParents" runat="server" 
     AllowPaging="True" 
     AllowSorting="True" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
     DataSourceID="edsParentList"
     PageSize="20" 
     onpageindexchanged="grdParents_PageIndexChanged" onsorted="grdParents_Sorted" >
     <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <a href="Parent.aspx?id=<%# Eval("ParentID") %>"><%# Eval("Name") %></a>
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="BirthDate" HeaderText="Birth Date" 
              DataFormatString="{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}"
              SortExpression = "BirthDate" />
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Children" SortExpression="Children.Count">
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="lblChildCount" runat="server" 
                  Text='<%# Eval("Children.Count") %>'></asp:Label>
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

This displays the grid fine.  However, when I click on the header of the Children column, this error is thrown:

> 'Count' is not a member of
>   'Transient.collection[FooEntities.Child(Nullable=True,DefaultValue=)]'.
>   To extract a property of a collection element, use a subquery to
>   iterate over the collection.

My question is: **How do I enable sorting on the .Count() of a navigation property which consists of a collection of child objects?**

Is there a way to specify this with SortExpression or do I have to break down and do all my paging and sorting manually? (Which I'd obviously prefer to avoid!)

Answer (score 1):

In your position, since the entity classes are declared as partial, I would try creating a supplemental partial class code file for the Parent entity, and add a ChildCount read-only property.  This property would reference the Children navigation property.  I would then sort on that.

I am assuming, here, that an EntityDataSource can work with what I'll call derived properties on an entity.  I have not tested this.

Comment: I believe this won't work, because the sort expression is used in Entity SQL and finally translated into a SQL ORDER BY clause. But if you define such a custom property, it doesn't correspond to a persisted column in the database and the query can't be executed. But... "I believe...", sure I am not...

Comment: Ann, Thanks for your answer.  I can extend the EF class by adding a property that relays the child count, but I can't figure out how to get this custom property to be recogninzed by the EntityDataSource.  I get a MappingException: The number of members in the conceptual type 'XXX' does not match with the number of members on the object side type 'XXX'.  I think Slauma might be right that there is no way to do this, but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced the error (in a simpler example) and I believe it is not possible to find any `SortExpression` that would perform a sorting on the children's count.

I have seen two important additional information:

- The exception thrown when you click on the column header is an `EntitySqlException`
- The last method in the stack trace which finally throws the exception is `EntityDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments)`

[ExecuteSelect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datasourceview.executeselect.aspx) is an `abstract` method of `DataSourceView` which is overriden by the various specific data source controls to perform the actual work to load data from the data store. In case of the `EntityDataSource` the corresponding view is the `EntityDataSourceView` and from the exception thrown - an `EntitySqlException` - I would conclude that `ExecuteSelect` builds the query using [**Entity SQL**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399560.aspx).

The argument `DataSourceSelectArguments` contains parameters defined in the `EntityDateSource` and also a `SortExpression` which is very likely just the sort expression you specified on the `TemplateField`. Those are used to compose the final query in Entity SQL.

I would assume that the `SortExpression` is just passed as an `ORDER BY` clause in the Entity SQL statement. This would look like:

```
ORDER BY Children.Count
```

But this is invalid Entity SQL. You can use dotted paths for a navigation reference, but you cannot use any "LINQ-like" methods or properties (like `Count`) of a navigation collection in Entity SQL.

It is possible to write a valid Entity SQL so sort by the children's count. According to [this example (search for "Order By - Related Entities" in the file)](https://adonetsamples.svn.codeplex.com/svn/EntityFramework/Beta3/Entity%20Framework%20Query%20Samples/EntitySQLSamples.cs) a correct Entity SQL statement would be:

```
"SELECT VALUE p2.p 
 FROM (SELECT p, ANYELEMENT(SELECT VALUE Count(c.ChildId) FROM p.Children AS c)
                 AS childCount
       FROM Parents AS p)
 AS p2
 ORDER BY p2.childCount"
```

(This is so hard to read that I even don't know how to indent the code semantically correct.)

I think this `ANYELEMENT(SELECT...` construct is the "subquery" the exception is talking about and wants to have in order to count the elements of the children collection.

Obviously you can't pass `p2.childCount` into `SortExpression` without the whole subquery which defines `p2`.

My conclusion: There is no hope to find a working `SortExpression` for the children count.

Maybe there is a way without using the `SortExpression` - for example by catching a click event on the header and then building the complete query manually in the event handler, but I do not really know, if and how it's possible.

Why do consumers of the `EntityDataSource` and `GridView` have to figure out that themselves? Did you anywhere see documented: "*When the data source is of type `EntityDataSource` the `SortExpression` of a `TemplateField` in a `GridView` must be a valid **Entity SQL** `ORDER BY` clause.*" I didn't. Just something like: "The `SortExpression` is an expression for sorting."

Unfortunately, because it is nowhere clearly said what happens with the `SortExpression`, what is the correct syntax and what kind of expressions are supported or not, this answer is more a guess than an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.  I've been playing with extending my EF object class with a custom property, but I haven't been able to get past the error: MappingException: The number of members in the conceptual type 'XXX' does not match with the number of members on the object side type 'XXX'.  I strongly suspect that you are right but I can't be sure until I figure out whether I can add the customer property to my EF generated class.