# EntityDataSource where association count > 0

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, count, entitydatasource

I'm trying to get Items that has at least 1 Chart, Items and Charts have a 1 to many relation.

I tryed this :

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" ContextTypeName="Entities"
EntitySetName="Items" Where="Count(it.ItemCharts) > 0" runat="server" />
```

But i get the error message :

> No overload of canonical aggregate function 'Edm.Count' is compatible with the arg...

How do I do this without using code behind?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I found a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917481/how-to-add-count-of-child-table-in-entitydatasource), but it is not answered :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [EXISTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399769.aspx) to determine whether a collection/association is empty:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" ContextTypeName="Entities"
EntitySetName="Items" Where="EXISTS(it.ItemCharts)" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Works! For my knowledge, what if I wanted Items that have at least 2 charts?

Comment: In theory you need to write `Where="(SELECT COUNT(0) FROM it.Charts) > 2"` but it seems it's not supported. See also [this table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896323.aspx) for supported comparisons.